# Security: Receive errSecParam error on query items having same label

Tags: swift, macos, security

Xcode 13.4.1 / macOS 12.5.1

I want to fetch all keychain items labeled specifically, but get an error. What I'm doing wrong?

A query dictionary is like:

```
    var request: [CFString: Any] = [
        kSecClass: kSecClassGenericPassword,
        kSecMatchLimit: kSecMatchLimitAll,
        kSecAttrLabel: "some common label here"
    ]
```

a request is

```
    var item: CFTypeRef?
    let result = SecItemCopyMatching(request, &item)
```

a returned error is

```
errSecParam = -50, /* One or more parameters passed to a function were not valid. */
```

Update:

with `kSecMatchLimit: kSecMatchLimitOne` the error is the same